# XAMPP and Skype Port Conflict on Windows 10

Tags: apache, xampp, skype, ports, windows-10

I know some of you knew that Skype usually conflicts with XAMPP, because of the port. However if you are trying to use Windows 10 there are no advance option on how to avoid Skype using ports like 80 or 443. (Sorry I can't find advance option on Skype on Windows 10)

Any hint on how to make Skype not to use ports 80 or 443 on Windows 10?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about unistalling Skype from Windows 10 and installing the desktop version? I'm not sure, because I don't own Win10, but in my Win8.1 I unistalled the Skype that comes with my PC and reinstalled the desktop version, then changed the ports in advanced settings. It worked for me. ^^

Comment: @ricardo-sohn I can't get classic version from Microsoft. When I go to https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/ , I can't find classic version from Microsoft.