# Windows 10 and XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp, windows-10

I am trying to start learning PHP (.Net is my main environment) and it looks like XAMPP is the way to go. I setup a new Windows 10 VM (Build #10074, so latest as of this writing) that has all updates installed.

I installed XAMPP without any trouble, Apache/MySQL start up without any issues (both normal and as a service) but when I try to browse to http://localhost I get a can't connect error. I've read in a few places that changing the port number can help, so I changed to 88 in the config (both places) and still no luck. I even tried connecting via http://[IP]:88, but still no dice. Skype is uninstalled (read that causes problems), IIS was never installed (so no World Wide Web Publishing Service) and everything says it's up, but I can't connect. I even turned off Windows Firewall completely, but still nothing.

The only error log entries are that it seems to be starting up fine minus the SSL config, which I don't care about:

```
[Wed May 20 06:19:42.427262 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1784:tid 596] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 20 06:19:42.427262 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1784:tid 596] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Wed May 20 06:19:42.427262 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1784:tid 596] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\dev\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/dev/xampp/apache'
[Wed May 20 06:19:42.427262 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1784:tid 596] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2744
[Wed May 20 06:19:42.708511 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2744:tid 500] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed May 20 06:19:42.786636 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2744:tid 500] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed May 20 06:19:42.817887 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2744:tid 500] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Access log is empty, so it's like it's not even trying to connect. Here is the full httpd.conf file (major comment blocks removed, but single-line entries left in case something needed enabled that wasn't):

```
ServerRoot "C:/dev/xampp/apache"
Listen 88

LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule auth_form_module modules/mod_auth_form.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
#LoadModule authnz_fcgi_module modules/mod_authnz_fcgi.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
#LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
#LoadModule cache_socache_module modules/mod_cache_socache.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule data_module modules/mod_data.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule heartbeat_module modules/mod_heartbeat.so
#LoadModule heartmonitor_module modules/mod_heartmonitor.so
#LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
#LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule lua_module modules/mod_lua.so
LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
#LoadModule macro_module modules/mod_macro.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
#LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
#LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
#LoadModule reflector_module modules/mod_reflector.so
#LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
#LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
#LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
#LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
#LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
#LoadModule session_crypto_module modules/mod_session_crypto.so
#LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
#LoadModule slotmem_plain_module modules/mod_slotmem_plain.so
#LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
#LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
#LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
#LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so
#LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_xml2enc.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>

ServerAdmin postmaster@localhost
ServerName localhost:88
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "C:/dev/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/dev/xampp/htdocs">
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                   default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                   home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/dev/xampp/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #
    # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
    # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
    #
    #Scriptsock cgisock
</IfModule>

<Directory "C:/dev/xampp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile "conf/magic"
</IfModule>

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
#Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf


# Various default settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf
# Implements a proxy/gateway for Apache.
Include "conf/extra/httpd-proxy.conf"
# Various default settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-default.conf"
# XAMPP settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"

# Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
#
# uncomment out the below to deal with user agents that deliberately
# violate open standards by misusing DNT (DNT *must* be a specific
# end-user choice)
#
#<IfModule setenvif_module>
#BrowserMatch "MSIE 10.0;" bad_DNT
#</IfModule>
#<IfModule headers_module>
#RequestHeader unset DNT env=bad_DNT
#</IfModule>

# XAMPP: We disable operating system specific optimizations for a listening
# socket by the http protocol here. IE 64 bit make problems without this.

AcceptFilter http none

# AJP13 Proxy
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
<IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
Include "conf/extra/httpd-ajp.conf"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas on how to get this running?

Comment: maybe you should try others like 'wamp' ? have u tried that ?

Comment: Try to change your port to some thing like 8081 or some free ports, but before that check the links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333203/xampp-couldnt-start-apache-windows-10 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932886/xampp-and-skype-port-conflict-on-windows-10 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758894/apache-server-xampp-doesnt-run-on-windows-10-port-80

Answer (score 1):

The port 80 is held by the Windows IIS (some publishing service).
Shutting down "some system process" may be tricky... you should rather edit the [Apache folder]/conf/httpd.conf and if you want to configure virtual host, use the new port in [Apache folder]/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf (I used 4900 instead of 80 and 4901 instead of 443 in [Apache folder]/conf/httpd-ssl.conf). And remember to use the port when accessing page on localhost (or your virtualhost), for example: localhost:4900/index.html

Answer (score 0):

a) Try a portscanner on your system. Maybe there is something else than Skype.

b) Also try to install xampp in the default folder (C:\XAMPP).

c) Try to start Apache & MySQL not as a service, start over the controlpanel of xampp.

d) Don't know how Win10 handles permissions. Maybe apache.exe can't access the folders.

e) Windows Firewall?

Comment: `Maybe there is something else than Skype. 
Maybe apache.exe can't access the folders.`
Please use comments sections if you're not sure of the answer.

Comment: I would if I could. If i click on "add comment" i get the following info: You must have 50 reputation to comment.

Comment: Yes, answer the questions you know better and earn reputation.

Comment: Sry, but sounds a bit funny! Do not answer like this, use comments. And yes, to comment you have to answer...

Answer (score 0):

For Apache to work you must disable (or not start) the **World Wide Web Publishing Service** service, as I understand that this is a version of Microsoft's IIS and will directly conflict with Apache.

Go to the **Services** administration dialog, find the **WWW Publishing Service**, open the dialog and disable it.

Apache works after this, however you may also need to play with the Apache Conf files too...