# Disabling Everything HTTP Server

Tags: apache, wamp

How can I disable Everything HTTP Server?

It is using port 80 and I cant start my wamp because of that. Even xaamp wont work. When Im testing port 80 it says,

Your port is actually used by:

Server: Everything HTTP Server

Comment: Possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758894/apache-server-xampp-doesnt-run-on-windows-10-port-80/30759095#30759095

Answer (score 0):

start > run > services.msc and you should the Everything server listed > right click and choose Stop

Comment: the service is called "ServiceEverything"

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have the

> voidtools - Everything Search Engine

installed.

Uninstall it as it has a little webserver in it that allows you to search from a browser.