# System using port 80 since upgrade to windows 10

Tags: php, windows, apache

Ever since I have upgraded to windows 10, port 80 has been in use by the system. Is there anyway that I can stop the system from using port 80? Or can I change the port that apache uses?

Thanks

Edit: The process that is using port 80 is PID: 4

Comment: Certainly you can change the port apache uses in the configuration. But I would say it makes more sense to find out _what_ uses that port! nothing should happen on your system that you do not know about. Though actually that is an impossible demand on a MS-Windows based system, I know.

Comment: this is usually or skype or maybe your IIS service is open.

try closing skype (maybe it's auto installed)
also try to close IIS (google on how to close it on win10)

Comment: @DanielKrom I will try to close IIS, as I have already uninstalled skype.

Comment: ok good luck! @arkascha solution is better but changing apache ports sometimes might be a complicated thing.

Comment: @DanielKrom Why should changing the configured port be complicated? You change that line in the configuration and reload the http server process. Nothing complicated there...

Comment: well I did it once and I messed up everything, if you are using xampp it's easy, but I had it in amazon AWS also had to update security groups and so, was a pain in the s

Comment: I never understood why people use those fancy "distributions" of something perfectly simple like an apache http server. But then again I am not really familiar with the MS-Windows platform. Seems like many things are more complicated there.

Comment: SEE -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758894/apache-server-xampp-doesnt-run-on-windows-10-port-80/31229606

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Windows 10, and for me, the culprit was the IIS service: "World Wide Web Publishing Service".  After stopping/disabling it, it freed up port 80.

Comment: It was that service. Just disabled it and port 80 freed.

Comment: Best option is to go to "Add/Remove Windows additional features" and remove Internet Information Services (IIS).

Comment: This advice is still relevant!  A recent windows 10 update (17th May 2018) "stole" port 80 - turning off WWW service fixed it - Thanks.

Comment: Yup, still relevant.  June 7, 2018 update enabled this service again.

Comment: in my case, was MsDepSvc - Web Deployment Agent Service ( windows 10, build 1809 )