# What program in Windows 10 uses port 80?

Tags: windows-10, port80, ampps

I updated my Windows 7 PC to Windows 10. When I start AMPPS it says `port 80 is used by another program`. What program uses port 80?

Comment: Is it possible that you may be running your own program multiple times? Consider adding tags to your question maybe `ampps` folks will spot it sooner. Is `ampps` compatible with Windows 10, have you checked their bugtracker for known bugs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

Comment: @RachelGallen your condescending is based on ignorance.  The OP is asking what is using port 80, making it so ampps cannot use it.  You think that because http clients connect to servers via port 80 that your comment is clever.  Actually though, "using the internet" will not occupy (bind to) port 80 in any way.  Yes, it will connect to a server that is listening on port 80, but it itself will not use port 80 for anything.  1, and only 1, program can bind to a given port for an ip.  Most programs, incl. those that "use the internet" never bind to ANY port (since they are not tcp servers).

Comment: @RachelGallen Um, I don't know what to say here.  You are exactly correct.  The port number for a web server is 80.  a WEB SERVER.  You originally commented "pretty much ALL OF THEM.  you use the internet right?"..  You said pretty much all programs use port 80.  I hate to inform you, pretty much all programs are not web servers.

Comment: @RachelGallen I think you meant that pretty much all programs are web CLIENTS that will connect to some server on port 80.  But that has nothing to do with the OPs questions, since virtually unlimited clients can connect to any port they want to at any time.  They do not bind the port.  In other words, web clients that connect to servers which are listening on port 80, do NOT occupy port 80 on the client machine.  I have written countless HTTP clients and servers.  I would not be commenting if I needed to do research.  You are blatantly ignorant on this one.  Sorry.

Comment: @EvandelaCruz: Considering the high percentage of bot-net-ed Windows PCs the original statement is possibly not _that_ far-fetched ;-))

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's probably the W3SVC (World Wide Web Publishing Service) service. See the answer below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31229606/1532882

1. Click the start menu
2. Type in **Services**
3. Sort by **Name**
4. Scroll down to **World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC)** and disable it

---

Per [phpvillian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31837914/1532882), you can also run the following to help determine the culprit (make sure you open the command line with elevated privileges, e.g. "Run as administrator"):

```
netstat -a -b
```

Comment: It was actually this in my case, but does disabling it would cause something to my windows?

Comment: If you are using IIS, then disabling this might adversely affect you.

Comment: I found that World Wide Web Publishing Service was the culprit.

Running netstat -a -b didn't reveal anything useful (it said "Can not obtain ownership information")

Comment: @james Late reply, but you may need to "Run as administrator" for this command to work. Got to love annoying Windows restrictions. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Step 4:  Scroll down to "World Wide Web Publishing Service" and disable it.

Comment: All right! Disabled, thank you man

Comment: Just a note for people coming here in 2019. This service gets re-enabled by some Windows 10 updates. I had mine disabled and it reactivated again.

Comment: Or use the command `net stop http`.

Answer (score 11):

You're likely referring to Skype as it's notorious to using port 80 without consideration. Open the command prompt and type netstat -a -b to get your answer. This question has been answered already and explains how to use netstat.

[How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

Comment: I don't have Skype instaled.

Comment: Then did you at least try what I said?

Comment: FYI Skype does like to use port 80, but can be disabled in Options -> Advanced -> Connection -> Uncheck [  ] "Use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections"

Comment: I upvoted you because that trick with `netstat -a -b` helped me discover that latest Avast versions have a clash with one of JBoss ports.

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem but already solved. You can find used port from Windows Firewall.

1. Click Start > Settings > Ethernet >Network and Internet > Windows Firewall
2. In the left pane, click Advanced Settings
3. In Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, click Inbound Rules.
4. Find Local Port 80 with Protocol TCP. in my case is "World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-In)"
5. Once you find it, stop or disable that rule from Windows Services (World Wide Web Publishing Service).

if needed restart your pc.

Comment: it's just a routing rule.