# URL doesn't work in localhost - 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling

My Website works on the [server](http://www.iseworld.org).
But when I install the codes on localhost I get a 404 error when I try to browse it.

Here is my `.htaccess` code

```
#Header unset ETag
#FileETag None

<FilesMatch ".(js|css|html|htm|php|xml|font|woff)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch ".(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js|css|pdf|font|woff)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>


Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On



RewriteRule ^(tr|en)/sitemap.xml(.*)$ _assets/sitemaps/sitemap-$1.xml$2 [NC,L] 

Redirect /yurtdisi-lise-egitimi /tr 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What is your local environment and configuration?

Comment: win 10 and xammp

Comment: Did you create a virtual host with local domain?

Comment: no i didn`t create its.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem! Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668594/create-a-virtual-host-in-xamp-windows-10)