# Database Xampp Apache

Tags: database, apache, xampp, port

I'm very newbie with database and I'm trying to use xampp local host database but it gives this error

```
10:34:15 AM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

10:34:15 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
 
10:34:15 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

10:34:15 AM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check

10:34:16 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues

10:34:16 AM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this

10:34:16 AM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums

10:45:36 AM  [Apache]   Uninstalling service...

10:45:38 AM  [Apache]   There may be an error, return code: 1223 - The operation was canceled by the user.
10:45:38 AM  [Apache]   Service was NOT (un)installed!

10:45:43 AM  [Apache]   Problem detected!

10:45:43 AM  [Apache]   Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!

10:45:43 AM  [Apache]   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!

10:45:43 AM  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application

10:45:43 AM  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

I googled many solutions but none of them worked if you want to help me I can give you remote of the server please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Server (xampp) doesn't run on Windows 10 (Port 80)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758894/apache-server-xampp-doesnt-run-on-windows-10-port-80)

Answer (score 0):

Run CMD as administrator, and run `netstat -ano | findstr :80`, and then check the output.

Find two lines that are just like this, but obviously the pid will differ:

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1234
#the fifth output is the pid number.
```

And run `taskkill /F /PID 1234`, 1234 is the pid number in this example, it will differ for you probably.

If you can't find the pid number , please post the output of `netstat -anb` in your question.

### OR

I wouldn't risk it, but:
because your question has the statement `10:45:43 AM  [Apache]   Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!`, you could just run `taskkill /F /PID 4.`